# Generate random long long C++

Tags: c++, random, c++17, mersenne-twister

### `int` generator

I currently generate deterministic pseudo-random `int`s using this code:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>
#include <stdint.h>

const uint32_t CurrentTime = static_cast<uint32_t>(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count());

std::mt19937 Mersenne = std::mt19937(static_cast<std::mt19937::result_type>(CurrentTime));

int Min = 3;
int Max = 6;
std::uniform_int_distribution<> Distribution(Min, Max-1);

int Result = Distribution(Mersenne);
```

### The problem

There's two problems with this:

1. The parameters for `Distribution` must be `int`s.
2. The result from `Distribution(Mersenne)` is an `int`.

### The question

How do I generate a random `long long` instead of an `int`, with the `Min` and `Max` parameters also being `long long`s instead of `int`s?

### The context

I'm creating a deterministic game (peer-to-peer architecture), and the large minimum-size of a `long long` is needed as a sort of fixed-point number (since `float`s can cause non-determinism).

I won't accept answers that:

- Use `float`s or `double`s
- Suggest generating an `int` and casting it to a `long long`
- Generate random numbers non-deterministically (i.e. mersenne is deterministic if the same seed is used)

I would much prefer a solution from the standard library if there is one.

Ideally, the solution should be at least as efficient as my existing code on a 64-bit machine.

Comment: `std::uniform_int_distribution<int64_t>` ? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Just check the documentation of the constructor https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution/uniform_int_distribution, it clearly says that it uses the member type which can be any int type.

Comment: @bolov shouldn't it be `std::uniform_int_distribution<long long>`?

Comment: The question is valid, I don't understand the down vote

Comment: The source I got the code from didn't specify a template parameter for `std::uniform_int_distribution<> ` (this is even the case with the example code on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)). I didn't even think about what the `<>` was for.

Comment: @Wyck the only legitimate use for `long long` is when you need to overload/specialize for all integer types. Else use `int` or `intN_t` or any of other integer aliases defined in `cstdint`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) says that the template parameter can be `long long`

```
long long Min = 3;
long long Max = 6;
std::uniform_int_distribution<long long> Distribution(Min, Max-1);

long long Result = Distribution(Mersenne);
```

Answer (score 1):

Would that work for you?

```
#include <climits>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); // Here you can use any seed to make it deterministic
    std::uniform_int_distribution<long long> distrib(LLONG_MIN, LLONG_MAX);
    
    for (int n = 0; n < 5; ++n)
        std::cout << distrib(gen) << ' ';
    
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```